# Retrieving all inherited entities and navigation properties in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a class defined as:

```
public class ElectronicFundTransfer
{
    public int Id { get; set;}
    public int OrganisationId { get; set; }
}
```

and two inherited classes:

```
 public class PayPal : ElectronicFundTransfer
{
    public BankAccount BankAccount { get; set; }
}

 public class PaymentCard : ElectronicFundTransfer
{
    public FxRate FxRate { get; set; }
}
```

Note that this has been simplified somewhat, there are additional classes that inherit and additional navigation properties.

Now, for an organisation I want to get all their `ElectronicFundTransfers`. This will return a list containing both `PayPal` and `PaymentCard`. I also want to include the `BankAccount` and `FxRate` respectively.

If I add these as comma separated values to the `Include()` method on the query it errors claiming that "PaymentCard doesn't have a property called 'FxRate'.

I tried doing:

`_unitOfWork.ElectronicFundTransferRepository.Queryable()
                .Where(o => o.OrganisationId == organisationId)
                .Include<PayPal>("BankAccount");`

But I get the error

> `Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.IQueryable<ElectronicFundTransfer>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<PayPal>'`

Can I do this in one query or will I need to call the DB for each type?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, you need a query for each type, or a Union.

Answer (score 0):

This answer implements Gert Arnold's comment:

```
        Context context = new Context();
        int orgId = 1;
        ElectronicFundTransfer[] paymentcards = context.PaymentCards.Where(pc => pc.OrganisationId == orgId).ToArray();
        ElectronicFundTransfer[] paypals = context.PayPals.Where(pp => pp.OrganisationId == orgId).ToArray();
        ElectronicFundTransfer[] all = paymentcards.Union(paypals).ToArray();
```

**Edit:** Another way to implement this is with Table-Per-Hierarchy. In this case, the context class only contains the following DbSet:

```
public DbSet<ElectronicFundTransfer> ElectronicFundTransfers { get; set; }
```

The query only requires one call to the database:

```
ElectronicFundTransfer[] all = context.ElectronicFundTransfers.Where(ef => ef.OrganisationId == orgId).ToArray();
```

Comment: I'm not too sure about the usage of `Union`, so I still do the trip to the DB 3 times but then group the results in one array?

Comment: In the original answer, there are two trips to the DB (one each for paymentcards and paypals). The union is performed on the resulting arrays. Casting paymentcards and paypals to arrays is an unnecessary step but makes the resulting code more legible. If you are comfortable with both paymentcards and paypals being stored in the same table (with a discriminator column), then the Edit might be preferable.